# When write "function" in ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started to learn ReactJS and done some tutorials. Have noticed that some write `function` and others do not. Some examples below. What is the difference? What should I use and when?

**Render**

With function

```
var $class$ = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
   return (
     <div />
   );
 }
});
```

Without function

```
const $class$ = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
});
```

**Update**

With function

```
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
  $END$
},
```

Without function

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  $END$
},
```

**Default Props**

With function

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    $END$
  };
},
```

Without function

```
getDefaultProps() {
  return {
    $END$
  };
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those without the `function` keyword are the result of using the new shorter ES6 method definitions.

You can read more here: [Method Definitions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

As far as I am aware, there is no notable difference in behaviour between a shorthand definition and including the `function` keyword other than the former having reduced support across environments.

Comment: I think with Babel transform, the support for both methods should be same.

Comment: @AkshayArora Of course, but potentially using babel doesn't satisfy every possible environment setup so it's still noteworthy :-)